# How to test a the retrieve method of my class without testing the insert in the same testcase?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd

I am learning unit tests (in a TDD-like approach).
I am creating a class that encapsulates an collection, it has 3 methods:

- store
- retrieveAllDocuments
- hasItem

I created one test: testRetrieveWhenEmpty, whici goes like this:

```
@Test
public void testRetrieveAllDocumentsWhenEmpty() {
    List<String> storedDocs = state.retrieveAllDocs();

    assertNotNull(storedDocs);
    assertEquals(0, storedDocs.size());
}
```

And then I made it pass.

Now I would like to create a testRetrieveAllDocumentsWhenNotEmpty, which would be like this:

```
@Test
public void testRetrieveAllDocumentsWhenNotEmpty() {
    state.store("test") //This is the only api point that I can use to insert things
    List<String> storedDocs = state.retrieveAllDocs();

    assertNotNull(storedDocs);
    assertEquals(1, storedDocs.size());
    assertEquals("test", storedDocs..get(0));
}
```

But now I have to implement the store method, so I created the following test method:

```
@Test
public void testStoreDocument() {
    state.store("test")
    List<String> storedDocs = state.retrieveAllDocs(); //This is the only api point I can use to see the content

    assertNotNull(storedDocs);
    assertEquals(1, storedDocs.size());
    assertEquals("test", storedDocs.get(0));
}
```

I see two problems:

1. These methods are identical.
2. I test two methods in each test, if the store fails, I get a message that the retrieve has a problem.

Using reflection would bind my test to my implementation, and I am trying to avoid it.
Changing the interface for better testing is hard to argument to my team mates.

**What approach do you take in these cases? (Is this case a problem at all?)**

Comment: please, not the typo with `..` in the lines with `storedDocs..get` !! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually does not need to be equals:

In `testRetrieveAllDocumentsWhenNotEmpty` you can add more than one document then check size, also you don't need to get all individual documents, you need to assert size is the correct.

This method asserts to get ALL documents in a non empty scenario, if you can assert you inserted 3, **AND as long the `testStoreDocument` exists**, you don't need to assert the document retrieve but yes the list size to know if ALL are returned.

```
@Test
public void testRetrieveAllDocumentsWhenNotEmpty() {
    state.store("test1") 
    state.store("test2") 
    state.store("test3") 
    List<String> storedDocs = state.retrieveAllDocs();

    assertNotNull(storedDocs);
    assertEquals(3, storedDocs.size());
}
```

In `testStoreDocument`, you need to get the document, you don't need to assert the size of stored documents.

```
@Test
public void testStoreDocument() {
    state.store("test")
    List<String> storedDocs = state.retrieveAllDocs(); //This is the only api point I can use to see the content

    assertNotNull(storedDocs);
    assertEquals("test", storedDocs.get(0));
}
```

Comment: You are right, I expressed myself in the wrong way: their logic and the methods they call are identical. What changes is the arguments content and quantity, which plays a small role in the verification code.

Comment: Your update makes sense; but I a newbie in unit tests. Could you please expand on the reasoning why I just need to assert size in one case and only content in the other?

Comment: the name of your methods is the answer.... :) that is why testing methods name's are do descriptive

Comment: Kind of, in my (naive) logic, if I am resting the retrieve all document, I would like to test if the documents retrieved are the same I added.

Comment: you must trust your tests and go from smaller to bigger, testing only missing parts of the biggers that smaller didn't cover

Comment: That is cool! Thanks a lot, I've learned something important today :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try shifting your view from writing "a (set of) tests per method" to "a test per useful behaviour" of the class you are testing.

If this class is both reader and writer of the data, it kinda makes sense to use its insert operations when testing the retrieval behaviour and vice versa.

I'd test the no items, one item, multiple items, has a specific item, does not have a specific item cases. These tests would implicitly test the store method as well.

Kevlin Henney's talk [programming with GUTs](https://vimeo.com/108007508) provides a good explanation about this concept.

Comment: This sounds interesting. As I said, I am still a newbie so I still need the grip on it. I will take a look at the video you sent. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mention before try to write your unit tests in a way they test scenarios. Every reader understands then better what you class is for. Since we do not just want to use a method, we want to achieve something with this method.

You can express this in the name of your tests like this: when{**SomethingHappens**}Then{**ThisIsExpected**} or given{**Situation**}Should{**BeHandledInThisWay**}

You could create tests like givenStoredDocumentsShouldBeAllReturned and whenDocumentIsStoredThenItCanBeRetrieved